# problems using both mouse buttons in my touchpad using Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, synaptics-touchpad

I have an a dell 3537 laptop and my problem is related to my touchpad driver (I think).

Usually when I click on both mouse buttons it performs like clicking on the middle mouse button on regular desktop mouse.

However that is not the case in Windows 10.

For some reason when I click on both mouse buttons it works, but at the same time it opens the search box that is included in Windows 10, and that is really annoying (and I am used to click on both mouse buttons).

However clicking on middle mouse button on regular desktop mouse works perfectly
without opening the annoying search box.

My touchpad driver is "Dell Touchpad 19.0.15.2" by Synaptics

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. In future, please try and use appropriate capital letters and punctuation in your questions (Your orginal question was one **very** long sentence).

Comment: Sorry man, but English is NOT my first language beside that this is my first time to post a question in here.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Dell laptop, I found this question while trying to solve the same issue.

I found some posts of reddit about this issue and here is the solution. 
Go to `Settings ->  Devices -> Mouse & touchpad -> Additional mouse options`, 
this will open the Mouse Properties window.

Click on the link that says `Click to change Touchpad settings` 
Go to `Buttons` and select `Do Nothing` from the drop down list for `Both Buttons`

`Save`

Then change it back to `Middle Button Click` and `Save`